# How to fix "Illegal schematic variable(s)" in mutually recursive rule induction?

Tags: recursion, isabelle

In Isabelle, I'm trying to do rule induction on mutually recursive inductive definitions. Here's the simplest example I was able to create:

```
theory complex_exprs
imports Main
begin

datatype A = NumA int
           | AB B
and B = NumB int
      | BA A

inductive eval_a :: "A ⇒ int ⇒ bool" and eval_b :: "B ⇒ int ⇒ bool" where
eval_num_a: "eval_a (NumA i) i" |
eval_a_b:   "eval_b b i ⟹ eval_a (AB b) i" |
eval_num_b: "eval_b (NumB i) i" |
eval_b_a:   "eval_a a i ⟹ eval_b (BA a) i"

lemma foo:
  assumes "eval_a a result"
  shows   "True"
using assms
proof (induction a)
  case (NumA x)
    show ?case by auto
  case (AB x)
```

At this point, Isabelle stops with 'Illegal schematic variable(s) in case "AB"'. Indeed the current goal is `⋀x. ?P2.2 x ⟹ eval_a (AB x) result ⟹ True` which contains the assumption `?P2.2 x`. Is that the 'schematic variable' Isabelle is talking about? Where does it come from, and how can I get rid of it?

I get the same problem if I try to do the induction on the rules:

```
proof (induction)
  case (eval_num_a i)
    show ?case by auto
  case (eval_a_b b i)
```

Again, the goal is `⋀b i. eval_b b i ⟹ ?P2.0 b i ⟹ True` with the unknown `?P2.0 b i`, and I can't continue.

As a related question: I tried to do the induction using

```
proof (induction rule: eval_a_eval_b.induct)
```

but Isabelle doesn't accept this, saying 'Failed to apply initial proof method'.

How do I make this induction go through? (In my actual application, I do actually need induction because the goal is more complex than `True`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proofs about mutually recursive definitions, be they datatypes, functions or inductive predicates, must be mutually recursive themselves. However, in your lemma, you only state the inductive property for `eval_a`, but not for `eval_b`. In the case for `AB`, you obviously want to use the induction hypothesis for `eval_b`, but as the lemma does not state the inductive property for `eval_b`, Isabelle does not know what it is. So it leaves it as a schematic variable `?P2.0`.

So, you have to state two goals, say

```
lemma
  shows "eval_a a result ==> True"
  and "eval_b b result ==> True"
```

Then, the method `induction a b` will figure out that the first statement corresponds to `A` and the second to `B`.

The induction rule for the inductive predicates fails because this rule eliminates the inductive predicate (induction over datatypes only "eliminates" the type information, but this is not a HOL formula) and it cannot find the assumption for the second inductive predicate.

More examples on induction over mutually recursive objects can be found in `src/HOL/Induct/Common_Patterns.thy`.

Comment: Thank you! You put me on the right track. Another thing I needed and that I found via the examples you mentioned is the keyword ``and``, which I need for my use case.

I wanted to prove this:

    lemma eval_a_eval_b_deterministic:
      shows "eval_a a x ⟹ eval_a a x' ⟹ x = x'"
      and   "eval_b b y ⟹ eval_b b y' ⟹ y = y'"

which I can now do (using an auxiliary lemma).