# Unable to figure out induct rule for mutually recursive predicates

Tags: isabelle

Can you suggest how to apply an induction rule to the following lemma?

```
datatype 'a expr =
  Literal "'a literal_expr"
| Var "string"
and 'a literal_expr =
  NullLiteral
| CollectionLiteral "'a collection_literal_part_expr list"
and 'a collection_literal_part_expr =
  CollectionItem "'a expr"

datatype 'a type = OclVoid | Set "'a type"

inductive typing and collection_parts_typing where
  "typing Γ (Literal NullLiteral) OclVoid"
| "collection_parts_typing Γ prts τ ⟹
   typing Γ (Literal (CollectionLiteral prts)) (Set τ)"
| "collection_parts_typing Γ [] OclVoid"
| "⟦typing Γ a τ; collection_parts_typing Γ xs σ⟧ ⟹
   collection_parts_typing Γ (CollectionItem a # xs) σ"

lemma
  "typing Γ1 expr τ1 ⟹ typing Γ1 expr σ1 ⟹ τ1 = σ1" and
  "collection_parts_typing Γ2 prts τ2 ⟹
   collection_parts_typing Γ2 prts σ2 ⟹ τ2 = σ2"
  apply (induct expr and prts)
  apply (induct rule: typing_collection_parts_typing.inducts)
```

The following questions contains a very simple examples:

- [How to prove lemmas for mutually recursive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53905744/how-to-prove-lemmas-for-mutually-recursive-types/53906944)
- [How to fix "Illegal schematic variable(s)" in mutually recursive rule induction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020622/how-to-fix-illegal-schematic-variables-in-mutually-recursive-rule-induction)

But my example is more complicated. And I can't understand what's wrong with my datatypes, predicates or lemmas. This exact theory can be reformulated without mutual recursion. But it's just a small fragment of my actual theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a plausible solution that is similar to the one provided in the accepted answer to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53905744/how-to-prove-lemmas-for-mutually-recursive-types/53906944). Please note that I changed some of the names of some of the elements in your definitions and that I relied heavily on `sledgehammer` to bring the proof to a conclusion.

```
datatype 'a expr =
  Literal "'a literal_expr"
| Var "string"
and 'a literal_expr =
  NL
| CL "'a clpe list"
and 'a clpe = CI "'a expr"

datatype 'a type = OclVoid | Set "'a type"

inductive typing and cpt where
  "typing Γ (Literal NL) OclVoid"
| "cpt Γ prts τ ⟹ typing Γ (Literal (CL prts)) (Set τ)"
| "cpt Γ [] OclVoid"
| "⟦typing Γ a τ; cpt Γ xs σ⟧ ⟹ cpt Γ (CI a # xs) σ"

lemma
  fixes Γ1 Γ2 :: 'a
    and expr :: "'b expr"
    and prts :: "'b clpe list"
    and σ1 τ1 σ2 τ2 :: "'c type"
  shows 
    "typing Γ1 expr τ1 ⟹ typing Γ1 expr σ1 ⟹ τ1 = σ1" and
    "cpt Γ2 prts τ2 ⟹ cpt Γ2 prts σ2 ⟹ τ2 = σ2"
  apply(
      induction Γ1 expr τ1 and Γ2 prts τ2 
      arbitrary: σ1 and σ2 
      rule: typing_cpt.inducts
      )
  subgoal by (blast dest: typing.cases)
  subgoal 
    by (metis 
        expr.inject(1) 
        literal_expr.distinct(1) 
        literal_expr.inject 
        typing.cases)
  subgoal by (blast dest: cpt.cases)
  subgoal by (metis cpt.cases list.discI list.sel(3))
  done
```

---

Isabelle version: Isabelle2020

Comment: Thanks! I've got it. One can induct over almost any variables for plain data types. But mutual induction is very sensitive to variables. It seems that one should specify as induction variables all variables from first assumptions.

Comment: @Denis Generally, you should specify the induction variables in a way such that they match the induction rule that you apply. In this case, the rule `typing_cpt.inducts` was used (see `lemmas a = typing_cpt.inducts`). From its structure it is easy to see that this rule can 'consume' `typing Γ1 expr τ1` and `cpt Γ2 prts τ2` and provide a proof for two predicates: one predicate that depends on `Γ1`, `expr` and `τ1` and another one that depends on `Γ2`, `prts` and `τ2`. In this case, the first predicate is `typing Γ1 expr σ1 ⟹ τ1 = σ1` and the second one is `cpt Γ2 prts σ2 ⟹ τ2 = σ2`.